# Adding an exe to start-up using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, exe, startup

Need a batch file that can add and remove a .exe file from the start-up.
Does any one know ho I could do it.
When I say start-up I mean the exe executes when The user log's on.
I am compileing the batch file with http://www.battoexeconverter.com/.

Comment: This isn't really programming. It's more of a http://superuser.com question

Comment: I am trying to make a program that can use batch to add to Start-up. and superuser will mainly say how to do it by hand not with batch.

Comment: I think that it can probably be either registered in the registry you can create a shortcut to the executable program in the startup folder using VBScript or JScript.

Comment: Yes but I am making a program using batch and I cant use any other programming languages because I am compiling it in to and exe.

Comment: If you are trying to make a program then say so. Which programming language? If you really are trying to make a program, then there is no batch file involved. How are you going to compile the .bat file into a .exe? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Now, what you really need to do is decide what you mean by "when I start the computer". That would imply a service, or a scheduled task triggered on computer start if that exists. Or do you really mean "when a user logs on"? You are going to need to be precise.

Comment: I mean when the user logs on. Sorry for not explaining properly.

Comment: That needs to be in the question rather than comments.

Comment: I have just added it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to control the list of applications that are started when a user logs on. The keys that determine that are:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Use the former to control applications started when any user logs on. Use the latter to control applications started when the current user logs on.

You want to do this in a batch file. So you need to use the standard tools for controlling registry keys. That means the `reg` tool.

So, add a value like this:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v MyApp /d myapp.exe
```

And remove the value like this:

```
reg delete HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v MyApp
```

If you want to use `HKCU` rather than `HKLM` then change the key appropriately. Obviously if you choose to use `HKLM` that will require elevation.

Do be prepared for the fact that many virus scanners will treat such activity as evidence that your program is malicious.

Comment: Can I ask how you compile a batch file into a .exe? What tool does that?

Comment: I use this [link](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/) It is good because it adds it own extra commands so you can use the mouse to intract with the batch file.

Comment: You should probably make that clear in the question too. Since without that info this really does not look like a programming question. In any case you could still argue that it is a superuser question, or perhaps serverfault.

Comment: Thanks I will do this in future

Answer (score 2):

If it's simpy an EXE, then copy it to the autostart-folder (or delete it from there):

```
C:\Users\thatsMe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
```

The name of this folder could change with different Windows-versons or localisations.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to load an exe file from startup folder. This is a typical signature for viruses to load itself on machines so for security, its best to load the exe via a batch file. This is just an opinion